# ASP.NET vnext and ServiceStack.redis

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Have anyone got ServiceStack.redis to work in asp.net vnext?
I have these dependencies added to project.json:

```
"ServiceStack.Common.Signed": "4.0.40",
"ServiceStack.Interfaces": "4.0.40",
"ServiceStack.Redis.Signed": "4.0.40",
"ServiceStack.Text.Signed": "4.0.40"
```

dnu restore installed the packages successfully, but when I try to compile my code in Visual Studio Code (OS X) i get: "The type or namespace 'ServiceStack' could not be found ....."

From dnvm list:

```
Active Version              Runtime Arch Location             Alias
------ -------              ------- ---- --------             -----
       1.0.0-beta4          mono         ~/.dnx/runtimes
       1.0.0-beta5-11497    mono         ~/.dnx/runtimes
  *    1.0.0-beta5-11672    mono         ~/.dnx/runtimes      default
       dnx-mono             mono         ~/.dnx/runtimes
```

Comment: Are you compiling agains't CoreCLR or agains't the full framework?

Comment: dnvm list: 
       1.0.0-beta4          mono         ~/.dnx/runtimes
       1.0.0-beta5-11497    mono         ~/.dnx/runtimes
  *    1.0.0-beta5-11672    mono         ~/.dnx/runtimes      default
       dnx-mono             mono         ~/.dnx/runtimes

Comment: Add that to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is solved by this nuget:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Redis.Core/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.